# Error de Cors en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Tengo una duda que he intentando  conseguir solución pero sin embargo no me ha quedado del todo claro, tengo una aplicación hecha en **AngularJS** que consume un **JSON** de una fuente externa, el detalle es el siguiente estoy usando el servicio `$resource` para realizar el `get` sin embargo me da error cors:

[image: Error Cors]

Sin embargo cuando uso Jquery con las funciones `$.ajax` o `$.getJSON` no me da error de Cors? ¿A qué se debe este comportamiento?

Dejo los *screenshots* del código :

[image: Código fuente]
[image: Recurso]

Request con `ajax` de **Jquery** da `200`: 
[image: Request con el ajax]

Mi pregunta es ¿Porque con las funciones de `ajax` y `getJSON` de **Jquery** no genera error de Cors y con el servicio `$resource` sí?

Comment: ¿Porque usas screenshoots para el código?

Comment: @RaulGuiu lo siento, lo tendré en cuenta para próximas publicaciones .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de usar `$resource`, deberías usar [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

> `$resource`: Es una "fábrica" que crea un objeto de recurso el cual permite interactuar con fuentes de datos [`RESTful`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) del lado del servidor.
>
> `$http`: Es un servicio que facilita la comunicación con servidores remotos `HTTP` vía [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) o [`JSONP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

El `endpoint https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json`, no es una `API REST`, es simplemente un archivo `JSON`, por lo cual no soporta el método `OPTIONS`.

Intenta hacerlo así:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  
  angular.module('httpExample', [])
  .controller('FetchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache',
    function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
      $scope.method = 'GET';
      $scope.url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json';

      $scope.fetch = function() {
        $scope.code = null;
        $scope.response = null;

        $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
          then(function(response) {
            $scope.status = response.status;
            $scope.data = response.data;
          }, function(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data || 'Request failed';
            $scope.status = response.status;
        });
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="httpExample">
  <div ng-controller="FetchController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="url" />
    <button id="fetchbtn" ng-click="fetch()">fetch</button><br/>
    <pre>http status code: {{status}}</pre>
    <pre>http response data: {{data}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tu respuesta me quedo todo más claro debo profundizar en los conceptos de rest y como trabajan los métodos, y con $http funcionó a la perfección.